# vue-devtools always disabled with nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-devtools

I am creating a new project using nuxt.js `v2.3.0`. When I run `npm run dev` in my IDE console everything compiles correctly but when I go to the page I get the following error: `Nuxt.js + Vue.js is detected on this page. Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author.`

Here is my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
const pkg = require('./package');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'spa',

  dev: true,
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
    bodyAttrs: {
      class: 'h-100'
    },
    htmlAttrs: {
      class: 'h-100'
    }
  },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '@/assets/app.css'
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vue-notifications',
    '~/plugins/vue2-sidebar'
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    // Doc: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/getting-starterd/setup
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    '@nuxtjs/toast',
    '@nuxtjs/font-awesome'
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  */
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://users:8000'
  },

  /*
  ** Auth module configuration
  */
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      password_grant: {
        _scheme: 'local',
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/oauth/token',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'access_token'
          },
          logout: 'api/logout',
          user: {
            url: 'api/user',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: false
          },
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: 'Bearer'
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: "/account/login",
      logout: "/",
      callback: "/account/login",
      user: "/"
    },
  },

  /*
  ** Toast configuration
  */
  toast: {
    position: 'top-right',
    duration: 2000
  },


  loading: {
    name: 'chasing-dots',
    color: '#ff5638',
    background: 'white',
    height: '4px'
  },

  /*
  ** Router configuration
  */
  router: {
    middleware: ['auth']
  },

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {

    }
  }
};
```

If I was running in production mode then I could understand but I'm not. I would expect vue-devtools to be running as normal.

Comment: How do u run your app?

Comment: @Aldarund I use 'npm run dev' in my IDE console and run the app in Chrome

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had to add the following to the nuxt.config.js:

```js
vue: {
  config: {
    productionTip: false,
    devtools: true
  }
}
```

Now devtools shows up

Comment: What version were you running when this worked? I'm on the latest v2.4.5 and had no luck. https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#devtools indicates we should be able to set `devtools` to `true` in the build config but that doesn't work for me either (nor in combination with this).

Answer (score 5):

#### tl:dr:

- `vue.config.devtools = true` in my `nuxt.config.js` does not work for me.
- I ran `nuxt generate --devtools`, then `nuxt start` and opened the website in my browser. Doing so I could use the Vue-Devtools.
- After that I now can still use the Vue-Devtools, even when running `nuxt dev` and no `vue.config.devtools` flag set in my `nuxt.config.js`

#### Full story

So enabling the `devtools` flag in `vue.config` as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351373/3725391) did not work for me either.

I first tried forcing the Vue-Devtools as described [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/tree/6d8fee4d058716fe72825c9ae22cf831ef8f5172#force-enable-the-devtools). Adding a Plugin to set the `window` properties as described in the link. But without luck.

Digging in the Nuxt code I noticed the `--devtools` flag for the `generate` command and wanted to see if the Vue-Devtools work at all with Nuxt.

After running `nuxt generate --devtools`, then serving the application with `nuxt start`, I finally could access the devtools. 
And now, even when running `nuxt dev` they are still accessible. And I don't have `vue.config.devtools` set at all in my `nuxt.config.js`. Weird. But maybe that helps someone.

More context: I am running Nuxt in `spa` mode, with target `static` as I don't have a Node server in the Backend and just want to build an SPA.

Comment: I like this answer. Because, code change just for debugging doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

As @joshua jackson stated worked for me, while `devtools: true` did NOT.

**Version:**

Nuxt.js v2.10.0

Vue v2.6.10

```js
vue: {
  config: {
    productionTip: false,
    devtools: true
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the snippet here: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-vue-config/

Answer (score 2):

in nuxt.config.js

```js
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  devtools: true,

  ...
}
```

Hope this help someone stopped here.

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting `vue.config.devtools = true` in `nuxt.config.js` didn't work.
But I managed to solve it by going to

- Extensions
- three dots on the right of the vue dev tools extension
- manage extensions
- Turn on "Allow access to file URLs"
- Restart browser and thats it

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

I have struggled to get this working and tried all of the steps written here.

My issue was I had to run the server on a specified port.

```js
server: {
  port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
  host: '0.0.0.0'
},
```

Adding this to `nuxt.config.js` solved the problem.

Comment: to add to this, if you force a different port without specifying it in nuxt config as shown above it will always struggle to load dev tools. Keeping it on 3000 has always worked best for me