# Vuex, Nuxt: Unknown action type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm building a simple app using nuxt + vuex. When commiting/dispatching I constantly get error "unknown action/mutation type: **name**". Also my mutations and actions don't display in vue devtools. On the other hand getters and state displaying as they should be.

store/products.js:

```
import getProducts from "~/api/products";

export const state = () => ({
  all: [{ isAvailable: false }, { isAvailable: true }],
});

export const getters = {
  available(state) {
    return state.all.filter((p) => p.isAvailable);
  },
};

export const actions = {
  async fetchProducts(context) {
    const response = await getProducts(true);
    const products = await response.json();
    context.commit("setProducts", products);
  },
};

export const mutations = {
  setProducts(state, products) {
    state.products = products;
  },
};
```

pages/products/index.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async created() {
    await this.$store.dispatch("fetchProducts");
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

**What I've tried**

1. Writing actions/mutations as following via arrow function

```
export const actions = {
  fetchProducts: async (context) => {
    const response = await getProducts(true);
    const products = await response.json();
    context.commit("setProducts", products);
  },
};
```

2. Writing actions/mutations in index.js
3. Copied example from [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store). State is working, mutations don't.

All above mentioned points didn't work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `await this.$store.dispatch("fetchProducts")`, could you try doing:

```js
await this.$store.dispatch("products/fetchProducts");
```

Since products is a Vuex module, to access it in actions, you must use `module/actionName`.

About the modules not showing up in vue-devtools, could you make sure your `nuxt.config.js` has the following:

```js
export default {
  mode: 'spa',
  devtools: true //<--------- make sure this is set to true
}
```

Please see this thread as well where people explain their own experiences using different versions of Vue - [vue-devtools always disabled with nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53346558/vue-devtools-always-disabled-with-nuxt-js)

Comment: That's worked, but is there a way not to specify module? Also in dev tools I still don't see mutations and actions.

Comment: @Neistow you can specify module name by assigning a `property name`

Comment: Is this a `nuxt` thing or new `vuex` feature? actions didn't require addressing the module in vuex.

Comment: Looks, it's not working with Nuxt 3